# Which HTML5/CSS3/JS-or-jQuery framework to use for this task?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-frameworks

New here and restarting web development after some time again, I've done online research here and on the web on state-of-the-art html5/css3 gui frameworks *for a concrete requirement*, but -- besides the common/popular *low-level* ui frameworks -- I wasn't able to find what I'm looking for. Perhaps some of you more experienced guys can help me further.

I'm searching for a HTML5/CSS3/JS framework that builds on top of a popular JS gui framework (like jQueryUI, Sencha Ext Core (Ext JS) or similar) and delivers a *foundation* for programming an online designer app offering a design workspace/workbench comparable to those in Photoshop, Dreamweaver, Eclipse, etc. 
The web designer is intended to be a kind of *HTML DIVs* composer (i.e. DOM based), instead of a *HTML5 Canvas* based app [like "Sketchpad" (http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/) or "LucidChart" (http://www.lucidchart.com/)].

The foundation should basically provide an online working environment with these key features:

- dockable panels for diverse "panel types" like tool palettes,
  tool parameters, object properties, ...
- dom-based design work area with zoom-in/out feature, optimally with rulers and grids.
- 'Command' based design operations with undo+redo mechanism (=operations history).

Which framework would you (or could I) use for this requirement?

Thank you very much for any suggestions, ideas or experiences.

Alessandro

P.S.: Which keyword combinations would be appropriate in this case for bringing up the right google search results? Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Seeing all these buzzwords and names makes me very inclined to think you're doing it wrong, but I shouldn't be so discouraging all the time...

Comment: What you are asking isn't a framework, it's a full-featured software package that cranks out HTML5 apps. I would have to agree with BoltClock: "you're doing it wrong."

Comment: You gona have to write it yourself.

Comment: @all responders: It's *not* really a "full-featured" software package, but a foundation for a such. So yes, I'll have to write one myself if there doesn't exist a more specialized, higher-level framework/platform/infrastructure for online editors/designers/composers yet. So I am searching for something like a "jQuery DOM Editor Framework", probably not yet existing [please, see also my comment on the 1st answer contribution here]. Any further ideas???

Answer (score 1):

jQuery *is* a framework.  My personal favorite at that. That said, what you need are several jQuery plugins to do the specific tasks you need.

At the same time, it sounds like you're trying to invent a new product. I would be surprised if there's already a framework to do all that you're asking for.  Did you want this framework to do all the heavy-lifting for you?

Comment: Yes, you're right saying that jQuery is a framework, but a "low-level" one. What I'm searching for is a, say, "higher-level" framework that takes jQuery or even jQueryUI as foundation and provides a frame for higher-level application tasks, here targeted at the special case of online compositors/designers (DOM based) -- maybe the term *infrastructure* or *platform* for online editors/designers would have been the better term for that. Analogous example from the Eclipse world: jQuery+jQueryUI equivs to EclipseRCP incl. SWT, and what I'm searching for would be Eclipse GEF, also a framework.

Comment: The answer is: it doesn't exist. You say you're not  asking for a "full-featured software package", but you are (and maybe don't realize it). You want to build something of the likes of [Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com/). Usually online site builders suck, they're the only ones that seem to be doing it right. Trust me, they didn't use any kind of magical-web-app-building-framework. You're on your own buddy. Try to build it yourself... we'd be happy to help you along the way.